# Return only the first and last items of an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to create a method named first_and_last. It should use one argument, an Array, and return a new Array with only the first and last objects of the argument.

Here is what I have so far, but the method seems to ignore the initial argument and just create a new array.

```
def first_and_last(a)
  arr = Array.new
  arr = ["a", "b", "c"]  
end
```

Comment: Hint: How do you access the first and last elements of `a`? What would happen if you did `[ x,y ]` where `x` and `y` represent those two things? In Ruby the way to access both the first and last elements of an array is crazy obvious if you even skim the documentation on Array.

Comment: What your current code does:
1) You have a method called `first_and_last` which takes a parameter called `a` (but never uses it)
2) You then create a new array and store it in a variable `arr`
3) You then set `arr` to `['a', 'b', 'c']` and return it.

How can you change that do to what you want to do?

Comment: `[a.first, a.last]`.

Comment: Or `[a.shift,a.pop]` or `a.minmax_by.with_index { |_,i| i }`

Comment: @sagarpandya82, if `a = [1]`, `[a.shift, a.pop] #=> [1, nil]`(should be  `[1,1]`). It's also destructive, of course.

Comment: @cary good points. I think the simplest solution (the one you mention) seems best here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `values_at()` method to get the first and last elements in an array like this:

```
def first_and_last(input_array)
  input_array.values_at(0,-1)
end
```

Depending on what behavior you're looking for, it might not work on arrays with 1 or 0 elements. [You can read more about the method here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at).

Comment: If `input_array` equals `[3]` or `[]`, your method returns `[3,3]` and `[nil, nil]`, respectively, which is what one wants. I therefore suggest you remove your penultimate sentence. Also, common practice would be to replace "use the `values_at()` method to" with "use [Array#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at) to", obviating the need for your last sentence.

Comment: I think it's a possibility that someone using a method called `first_and_last` might not expect to get the same element back twice in their result. Using your example of input `[3, 3]`, they might expect something like `[3, nil]` or just `[3]`. It's also possible they might want the method to raise an exception instead of giving anything back. And I'm on the fence about using hash notation for instance methods because it can add another layer of confusion for beginner developers.

Comment: Suppose you want the first and last elements of `[1, 2, nil]`? That would be `[1, nil]`, so you can't interpret that to mean the receiver is a one-element array. I think the coder simply needs to check if the receiver has zero, one or more than one element. I don't understand what you mean by "...about using hash notation for instance methods...".

Comment: I agree that returning a nil is a bad idea if the input array can contain nil. That is part of why I mentioned the other option of returning an array with a single element. Again it really depends on the circumstance, which is why I mentioned that the reader might want to do a little research themselves instead of telling them what they must want.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use .first for the first element in the array, and .last for the last element in an array.

```
def first_and_last(arr)
  [arr.first, arr.last]
end 

p first_and_last([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Or....

```
def first_and_last(arr)
   [arr[0], arr[-1]]
end 

p first_and_last([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Comment: This works too. You could shorten the method body to one line as: `[arr.first, arr.last]`

Comment: Much too much code. This should be one line only, and there are several ways to do it. `[arr.first, arr.last]` is perhaps the clearest.

Comment: 1. This is the right idea and a good refactor. 2. Usually it's best to print the return value of the method, rather than making the method responsible for printing. So in this case remove the `p` from your method and instead write `p first_and_last([1,2,3,4,5,6])` instead.

Comment: Using `shift` and `pop` is incorrect (as well as being destructive): `first_and_last([1]) #=> [1, nil]`. I suggest you expunge that option.